# Proof that a boundary point cannot be an interior point and vice-versa.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Show that it is impossible for a boundary point to also be an interior point, and
vice-versa. A rigorous proof would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What definitions do you  have for boundary and interior points? I think this "nearly" follows from the definition that I saw in a basic topology textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us recall the definitions: let $A$ be a set of some topological space $(X;\tau)$.

- We say that $a\in A$ is an interior point if there exists an open set $O\in\tau$ such that $a\in O\subset A$.
- We say that $a\in A$ is a boundary point if for every open set $O\in\tau$ such that $a\in O$ we have $A\cap O\neq\varnothing$ and $(X\setminus A)\cap O\neq\varnothing$.

So let us suppose first that $a\in A$ is an interior point, and show that it is not a boundary point. By the definition there exists an open set $O\subset A$ that contains the point $a$. Therefore $(X\setminus A)\cap O=\varnothing$, so the condition of the second definition does not hold. Can you prove the other way?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to refer to the set in the second condition(for qualification as a boundary point) as $A^{C}$ instead of $X∖A$?

Comment: That is personal preference; choose the one you prefer.